# WordPress AMP for Custom Post Types with own URL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, amp-html

I want to use AMP with a Custom Post Type in WordPress.
For this reason, I've added the following code to my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'amp_init', 'xyz_amp_add_review_cpt' );
function xyz_amp_add_review_cpt() {
    add_post_type_support( 'xyz-review', AMP_QUERY_VAR );
}
```

The code is from the official plugin documentation: https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/blob/master/readme.md#custom-post-type-support

After that I've flushed my rewrite rules as they said.
Unfortunately it doesn't work for my CPT. Only for normal posts.

I think it's because my CPT has no slug. The URL is the same as for posts: example.com/custom-post-type-post/

If I add a slug to the CPT, the AMP will work.
But I couldn't do that.

Is there any other solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^([^/]+)+[\/]+(amp)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=xyz-review&name=$matches[1]&amp=1', 'top' );
```